# Boxedapp packer packed executable finds for file outside package

Tags: vb.net, packer

i have two files from which one is the main executable and other is run by first one. I want to pack these files into one executable, but with boxedapp packer or enigma virtual box the main executable file searches for the other file outside the packed exe file. I tried the option `share virtual environment with child processes` but it did not work. By the way the main exe is made from vb.net which needs a file in current directory. Please help me.

Comment: Have you written to BoxedApp support already? They are available even in Skype (check boxedapp website).